# PHP Undefined variable $_LIT["something"]

Tags: php, html, arrays

In my config.php, I have this array:

```
$_LIT = array(
    /* Адрес сайта */
    "url" => "http://learnit.loc/", // Адрес сайта
....
);
```

The problem is, that I cant use this array in code below:

For example, I have a mail-method and I have to put `$_LIT["url"]` in my special link variable.:

```
function testMethod($username, $email) {
$link = $_LIT["url"]."scipts/activate.php?link=".rand(0, 999999).rand(0, 999999).rand(0, 999999).rand(0, 999999).$username."activationLink";
}
```

And... I cant use it (`$_LIT["url"]`). It just put nothing, where the site url should be.

What I can also say, that I use my config.php in my ohter .php files using "`require_once`" "`config.php`". So I can get `$_LIT["something"]` there, but not directly in confing.php. Why?

Thanks for every help.

Comment: Because `$_LIT` isn't in the scope of your function. Read more abouts scopes in the PHP manual.

Comment: So you said that you placed this variable in the `config` and `config` is always available everywhere or there must be a method to load `config`. Are you using some framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables that are outside of functions scope cannot be accessed directly.

You need to use the keyword `global` inside function.

like  `global $_LIT`

```
$link = $_LIT["url"]."scipts/activate.php?link=".rand(0, 999999).rand(0, 999999).rand(0, 999999).rand(0, 999999).$username."activationLink";
```

Link to Documentation.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

---- update----

```
function testMethod($username, $email) {
    global $_LIT;

     $link = $_LIT["url"]."scipts/activate.php?link=".rand(0, 999999).rand(0, 999999).rand(0, 999999).rand(0, 999999).$username."activationLink";
}
```

Comment: Yes. But now a have this error (global $_LIT["url"];) : syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: You could also give it as a parameter in the function.

Comment: actually, it would be `global $_LIT;` but globals are ugly

Answer (score 0):

To use global variables inside function or class scope, you need to use the `global` keyword:

```
function testMethod($username, $email) {
       global $_LIT;
       $link = $_LIT["url"]."scipts/activate.php?link=".rand(0, 999999).rand(0, 999999).rand(0, 999999).rand(0, 999999).$username."activationLink";
}
```

More in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 0):

The $_LIT variable is being declared outside the function scope. You can access it within the function scope by declaring it as global, like so:

```
function testMethod($username, $email)
{
    global $_LIT;
    $link = $_LIT['url'];
}
```

Another way would be to add the $_LIT variable as a dependency of your function; this allows you to alter the behaviour of the function easily in future, if you need to provide localisation for example.

```
function testMethod($username, $email, $config)
{
    $link = $config['url'];
}
```

Then call the function like so:

```
testMethod('username', 'email', $_LIT);
```